# Getting Access Token in Google+ using Google+ API

Tags: c#-4.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I am creating an desktop application that uses google+ API, to get the profile information.

I used this [sample](http://gusclass.com/blog/2012/08/31/using-the-google-net-client-library-with-google/) .It has certain limitations.

```
     1.It uses the default browser for logging in(using Process command).
     2.After logging in the user has to copy the access code from browser.
```

I want my application to handle all these things.The user has to enter the login credentials in the embedded browser(in my App) that redirects to login page.**My app should be able to retrieve the access token in the browser without the need of copying by user** .

Is there any other methods in C# to get the access token instead of copying it everytime by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application can read the launched browser's window title, the authorization code that you need is contained in the window title of the confirmation page. This ability is restricted in JavaScript environments such as PhoneGap, but in a desktop environment with elevated priviledges I think there is likely a way to do it. I don't have code for you but hopefully that gives you the method to pursue. After you programmatically read the auth code from the title, you would then want to close the launched browser.